# How to get default variable definitions for a method

Tags: php, reflection, methods

Using PHP's ReflectionClass. Is this possible?

I want to get a list of methods and the defined variables and if possible their default values too.

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($var);
$methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

print_r($methods); // only method names here :(
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php

Comment: thanks! you should post that as an answer, or i delete my q :P

Comment: hmmm but how can I pass the method name to it? `array($var, $method->name)` doesn't seem to work, because that thing expects a string...

Comment: ok i found out, I had to use ReflectionMethod instead of ReflectionFunction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ReflectionParameter::getDefaultValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.getdefaultvalue.php) method.  With your code example:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($var);
$methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
$methodParameters = array();

foreach ($methods as $method) {
    $parameters = $method->getParameters();
    foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
        $name = $method->getName() . '::' . $parameter->getName();
        $methodParameters[$name] = null;
        if ($parameter->isOptional()) {
            $methodParameters[$name] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
        }
    }
}
```

---

An example:

```
class a {

        public function methodOne() {
        }

        public function methodTwo($param) {     
        }

        public function methodThree($param = 'foo') {
        }

}

    $var = new a();

    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($var);
    $methods = $reflection->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
    $methodParameters = array();

    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        $parameters = $method->getParameters();
        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
            $name = $method->getName() . '::' . $parameter->getName();
            $methodParameters[$name] = null;
            if ($parameter->isOptional()) {
                $methodParameters[$name] = $parameter->getDefaultValue();
            }
        }
    }
    var_dump($methodParameters);

// results in this array:

array(2) {
  ["methodTwo::param"]=>
  NULL
  ["methodThree::param"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

Comment: just wondering, is the parameter list always returned in the original order?

Comment: Good question, let me do a little bit more testing...one sec.  @Alex [Here's an updated codepad.viper script](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1Ozhxp) ...it appears the parameters are returned in order